# About run ruby script in controller with daemon mode

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run a ruby script from my rails controller.
The script runs successfully when the rails server is started normally as

rails s

But when rails server is started as a daemon, the ruby script fails to run.

rails s -d

Inside the controller the ruby script is run with  the "system , %x ,exec" commands.

But it is not working for me..please give me any solution for this

Comment: Try `Process.spawn`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#method-c-spawn

Comment: What is exactly is "not working". What is logged? What happens exactly? Please show the exact code you are using and describe how you are calling it.